# How to reinstall Android on Polaroid PSPT350

Tags: installation

Some months after i bought my cellphone it begans to download many apps by itself and now it simply doesn't work. Every time I turn it on, a think called "Mlhiw" don´t let me use it and turn off my cellphone. So I want to reinstall Android on it. It have Android 4.4.2. And I have no idea about how to reinstall it.

Comment: Pretty sure those are malwares! Your phone is infected by them. It's quite easy reinstalling the phone firmware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need flash files and a flashing software. Your phone has a Mediatek (MT6572) chip, so you need SP FlashTool to be able to flash the phone.

1. Flash files and flashtool can be found [here](http://www.needrom.com/download/polaroid-pspt350/) (Just sign up to the site otherwise you won't be able to get those files).
2. MTK VCOM drivers [here](https://androidmtk.com/download-mtk-usb-all-drivers)

   - Unzip the files, go to SP Flashtool folder and run the exe file
   - Install the drivers.
   - Open flashtool the click on Scatter-Loading
   - Browse to the flash files folder
   - Select the MTxxxx-Android-scatter.txt
   - Now just uncheck the Preloader field the click on Downloading (Green arrow)
   - Now connect your phone (power off), drivers should be installed and the flashing process start.
   - Wait till the end: a big green checkmark should pop up.
   - Phone flashed and problems gone.

**DON'T FLASH THE PRELOADER, YOUR PHONE MAY BE PERMANENTLY BRICKED (No powering on, no charging, no being detected by the computer).**

Comment: Yesterday finally I had time to resolve this. I used the steps you described and it worked! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I helped.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reinstall Android in order to "clean" your device.
You just have to go to settings>Back up and reset>Factory reset the device (the names may vary from device to device) but are like this.
So when you do this, what really happens is that the device is restored to a new device (just as you bought).

Take in mind that all your data will be erased, so back up your data first.

Comment: How do you deal with sticky malware that install as system apps?

Comment: If that is the problem(I'm not sure if the problem AngeLOL reported is like that) you can root the device and uninstall the unwanted apps(try with kingroot which has a built in tool for that).

Comment: Sure, for an experienced user may do that, but he stated he can't use the phone because of (1) some app is not letting him to. And also  (2) His phone was downloading apps by itself. What do you think it can be? And you can't be sure if all the malware will be removed.

Comment: @esQmo_ Plus, both Kingroot and Kingoroot share a fame of being shady software.

Comment: We know that those rooting softwares send user activities to some servers in china

Comment: Anyway, I think that he has to give a try to a factory reset, and look if it helps (also I wouldn't advice to flash if he has no experience on that field, because he can easily brick the device).

Comment: I tried a factory reset, but "Wlhiw" and many others like "koala service" are still installed , thats the reason I want to reinstal

Comment: @AngeLOL So flash it! Or if you can, use ADB shell to manually uninstall them